# AdroitLogic UltraStudio (Windows), component images/Icons not displayed in flows

Tags: esb, ultraesb, adroitlogic

Downloaded AdriotLogic UltraStudio (on Windows)

Installed as suggested @ https://developer.adroitlogic.com/ultrastudio/docs/17-01/ultrastudio/installation.html on IntelliJ 2017.1.2.

Component Icon Images not displayed in the stdio.

[image]

Comment: installed on Community edition IntelliJ 2017.1.2

Comment: I assume you are having an internet connection? as these icons are looked up from the internet on the first run.

Comment: please fix AdriotLogic to AdroitLogic once the pending edit got approved or rejected

Answer (score 3):

Click on File -> Settings menu item, then go to UltraStudio settings section under Tools section. In there for the Icon Theme setting value, make sure below URL is specified [as shown in here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up6Et.png)

https://developer.adroitlogic.org/ultrastudio/icons/default/

NOTE: You need to connected to internet since the component icon images are downloaded from a remote icon repository.

Comment: I have the same url, but doesn't work. Check if the anti virus is blocking anything, no luck there.

Comment: upon further anaysis found that it was indeed due to Anti-virus. Once disabled I can see the icons. Can you pls tell me the process that download the images, so that i can selectively enable the access. This way i don't have to disable anti-virus?

Comment: What is the Anti-virus software you are using?